# What's the correct notion of equivalence in a double category?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, groupoids

What's the appropriate notion of equivalence between two objects in a double category?

---

At first I thought the answer was just an equivalence in one of the associated $2$-categories, but then I realized that objects can be equivalent in the horizontal $2$-category without being equivalent in the vertical $2$-category, or vice-versa. For example you can write down a double category which is a discrete set vertically and terminal horizontally.

So I assume that the correct definition requires equivalences horizontally and vertically, and then some squares relating them. But I can't see the correct requirements for the squares.

Comment: A double category is a category object internal to $\mathbf{Cat}$, so presumably you could try to spell out what "equivalence of categories" is internal to $\mathbf{Cat}$, and that would at least be a compelling candidate in some senses.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is *a* correct notion. A double category is a couple of interacting 2-categories, moreso than a generalization of a single 2-category.

For instance in the double category of categories, functors, and profunctors, which is even a proarrow equipment, a vertical equivalence is an ordinary equivalence of categories, while a horizontal equivalence is a Morita equivalence, in this case an equivalence up to splitting of idempotents. The notions are distinct and separately significant, and it's complicated to see internally when a horizontal equivalence gives rise to a vertical one.

Comment: I suppose what I'm looking for is the "maximally strict" notion of equivalence. So in your example it would be ordinary equivalence of categories.